# display column even when. the count is zero/does not appear

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to summarize a few events based on EIDs, but the result is only displaying for `eve_1` and not `eve_2` since (based on my data) since `eve_2` count is 0.

How can I display eve_2 even when the count is 0 in this case?

```
Table 
| where DateTime > ago(7d) 
| where EID in (11, 22, 33)
| extend
Evet_cat = case(EID in (11 22), "eve_1", 
                EID == 33, "eve_2",
                "others"
                ),
Date_time = format_datetime(DateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')
| summarize count() by Date_time, Evet_cat
| order by Date_time desc
```

How can I make sure both eve_1 and eve_2 are displayed even if their count is 0?

Update: I realize my wording of the question may be wrong. What I'm looking for is that. I'm trying to set a default (0) for any column that does not have a count, if there is a count, that should be displayed as usual.

So, something like:

```
|   Date_time   | Evet_cat | count_ |
|---------------|----------|--------|
| 2023-02-24 13 | eve_1    |     10 |
| 2023-02-24 13 | eve_2    |      0 |
| 2023-02-24 12 | eve_1    |      5 |
| 2023-02-24 12 | eve_2    |      0 |
```

the original query I had would have produced something like this:

```
|   Date_time   | Evet_cat | count_ |
|---------------|----------|--------|
| 2023-02-24 13 | eve_1    |     10 |
| 2023-02-24 12 | eve_1    |      5 |
```

Ultimately, I am looking to get the data to display like this:

```
|   Date_time   | eve_1    | eve_2  |
|---------------|----------|--------|
| 2023-02-24 13 |    10    |      0 |
| 2023-02-24 12 |     5    |      0 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let Table = materialize(range i from 1 to 200 step 1 | extend DateTime = ago(7d * rand()), EID = tolong((rand(3) + 1) * 11));
// Solution starts here.
Table 
| where DateTime > ago(7d) 
| where EID in (11, 22, 33)
| extend Evet_cat = case(EID in (11, 22), "eve_1", EID == 33, "eve_2", "others")
        ,Date_time = format_datetime(DateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')
| evaluate pivot(Evet_cat, count(), Date_time)
```

| Date_time | eve_1 | eve_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-17 20 | 0 | 2 |
| 2023-02-22 23 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-02-23 23 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-02-18 11 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-02-18 08 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-02-22 08 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-02-21 14 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-02-18 17 | 2 | 1 |
| 2023-02-19 17 | 2 | 0 |
| 2023-02-24 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-23 12 | 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-02-24 03 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-23 01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-22 15 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-02-20 08 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-20 00 | 0 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WQPW/CQAyG9/yKV1m4a8PHhYGhohNIdKBL2aMrMeGkJBddTPohfnwdCKB682u/9mNPp/iwVVMScssWBdUULDtfT/DuGY0NDH8AHwmtL0+XSlQSY2c/xbREZZmCs6X7JRVsXRAcDsFXMGCPdDZDy9RIdgZ9M9U5VuLYuao328KrRY4niDNXWidYv61EZ1/6ulDqIs81nmG0dBmj9Us0FeQBRWYLYIsjBZpEV6TojK8+f+x5HfboR61f42ooYxKkaYL5XEd3wHVHnO0tC8jetqT+NwtkTB1lJh5ol+IetFS02MuzQhvrCEMkPUnG15MPPsjLMvk29Yq6USYY/UiMt9txnmOzGV2AOluepAGN6zyrG1iCvT/VrATlPlr/AQeECSjKAQAA)

Comment: Ha! I see what you're saying, I update the question for clarity. Thank you!